# Why get accessor does not allow the modification of object returned?

Tags: c#, properties, accessor

Please have a look at the code below:

```
public class Foo
{
    public System.Windows.Rect s
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Foo()
    {
        s = new System.Windows.Rect(-2, -3, 4, 5); // affects object
        s.Inflate(1.5, 1.5); // no effect at all
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make the non-const *Inflate()* method work in this case? If it does not modify my objetc, it means that my *Rect* object is deeply copied when I access it?

These are my interrogations, but the real question is: **why the accessor disallow modification of the object returned if there is a setter too?**

Comment: `Inflate` returns a new object which you have to assign to `s`

Comment: @Sergii: Where do you see that? Doc says that it returns void: [Rect.Inflate Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms558114(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That's just another example of why mutable structs are to be avoided...

Comment: @sstan you are right - the first link I got was the static version of the [Inflate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms558120(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: @Sergii: you just suggested a way to work around it: `s = System.Windows.Rect.Inflate(s, 1.5, 1.5)`, thanks!

Comment: @lionel you're welcome. this is the first time when my inattention actually helped :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.Windows.Rect` is a structure. Therefore a copy of the struct is returned by the property, rather than a copy of a reference to an object.

Modifying the returned value does nothing, as it's a copy of the value that's actually stored in the backing field for the property. If you try to make the modification directly, the compiler will actually give you an error, because it understands the problem:

```
// Error: CS1612 Cannot modify the return value of 'Foo.s' because it is not a variable
s.X = 10;
```

It doesn't do that for method calls as it doesn't know that the method call mutates the struct.

Moral: avoid mutable structs where possible... they cause pain.